# How do you increase the translation speed after zooming in?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, user-controls

I have a control that zooms in and out, and pans. By clicking a choice of two buttons, the user may zoom in or out respectively. My issue is with the translations after zooming in or out: If I zoom out to about .2F, I have to click-pan multiple times to move the same distance I could have at base 0. I seemed to solved this by dividing the zoom by its self squared: z/(z*z) but that seems to transform the entire matrix - and I'm NOT translating the matrix with this on any line!

Here is my code:

```
Matrix mtrx = new Matrix();
mtrx.Translate(pan.X, pan.Y);
mtrx.Scale(zoom, zoom);
e.Graphics.Transform = mtrx;

// To-Do drawing code here
```

Basic notes:

- Zoom increases and decreases by .12F on button click event
- The control being painted on is an inherited UserControl class
- The developing environment is C# 2010
- The drawing code deals with two rectangles who's location is {0, 0}
- I just want to be able to pan at the same speed as I can at base 0 (not zoomed in or out) when I am zoomed in or out a ways. ~ no motion-lag feelings

EDIT: I've updated the code above to an improved version of what I was dealing with before. This handles the panning speed for after zooming, but the new issue is with where the zoom is taking place: it's as if the point of zoom is being translated as well...

Edit: How I would do this in 3D (XNA):

```
public class Camera
{
    private float timeLapse = 0.0f;
    private Vector3 position, view, up;

    public Camera(Vector2 windowSize)
    {
        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(this.position, this.view, this.up);
        projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.Pi / 4.0f,
                           (float)windowSize.X / (float)windowSize.Y, 0.005f, 1000.0f);
    }
    //Sets time lapse between frames
    public void SetFrameInterval(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        timeLapse = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
    }

    //Move camera and view position according to gamer's move and strafe events.
    private void zoomHelper(Vector3 direction, float speed)
    {
        speed *= (float)timeLapse; // scale rate of change
        direction *= speed;
        position.Y += direction.Y;
        position.X += direction.X;      // adjust position 
        position.Z += direction.Z;
        view.Y += direction.Y;
        view.X += direction.X;      // adjust view change
        view.Z += direction.Z;
    }
    //Allows the camera to move forward or backward in the direction it is looking.
    public void Zoom(float amount)
    {
        Vector3 look = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Vector3 unitLook;
        // scale rate of change in movement
        const float SCALE = 0.005f;
        amount *= SCALE;
        // update forward direction
        look = view - position;
        // get new camera direction vector 
        unitLook = Vector3.Normalize(look);
        // update camera position and view position
        zoomHelper(unitLook, amount);
        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(position, view, up);
    }

    //Allows the camera to pan on a 2D plane in 3D space.
    public void Pan(Vector2 mouseCoords)
    {
        // The 2D pan translation vector in screen space
        Vector2 scaledMouse = (mouseCoords * 0.005f) * (float)timeLapse;
        // The camera's look vector
        Vector3 look = view - position;
        // The pan coordinate system basis vectors
        Vector3 Right = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(look, up));
        Vector3 Up = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(Right, look));
        // The 3D pan translation vector in world space
        Vector3 Pan = scaledMouse.X * Right + -scaledMouse.Y * Up;
        // Translate the camera and the target by the pan vector
        position += Pan;
        view += Pan;
        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(position, view, up);
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
Camera cam; // object
effect.Transform = cam.viewMatrix * cam.projectionMatrix;
// ToDo: Drawing Code Here
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Matrix mtrx = new Matrix();  
mtrx.Scale(zoom, zoom);  
mtrx.Translate(pan.X/zoom, pan.Y/zoom, MatrixOrder.Append);   
e.Graphics.Transform = mtrx;  
// To-Do drawing code here
```

Comment: Well, technically that's the same thing as I have above, only calculated differently. I tested it out and the zooming-point still moves with everything else instead of remaining at the center of the screen (or upper left of the screen as indicated by this code).

Google Maps presents the same (or similar) action that I want to achieve; I successfully did this in 3D space, but I can't seem to implement it here...

Comment: I took a look at the Matrix class in C#. I have edited the code above. Note the append argument. This should work. You first scale everything around zero and then move. This is the same as multiplying the scale matrix with the translate matrix in the correct order.

Comment: Alright, so I updated this in my code and the results are a bit funky: The zooming part zooms at the center like normal until you pan it once, then when you zoom out, it zooms out in the direction panned from the center. Also, the panning part, when zoomed in/out a ways, increases or decreases it's speed by about x1.5. None the less, I appreciated your efforts in trying to solve this! I've added the code I would use in 3D that already works above; hopefully that may shed some light...